# Process three lines together and repeat the process when delimiter is found until end of line

Tags: text-processing, monitoring

We will have a scenario where we check the status of a cluster and if any issues are found, we want to take 3 attributes of the output and send the information to an event management system.

This is the output:

```
          Name : host1.domain.com
       Address : 10.10.10.1
Overall Health : DISK_ERROR
--
          Name : host2.domain.com
       Address : 10.10.10.2
Overall Health : MEMORY_ERROR
--
          Name : host3.domain.com
       Address : 10.10.10.3
Overall Health : HEALTH_GOOD
--
```

What I was hoping to do was take each line, grab the value to the right of the colon and assign each value to a variable and then pass that in an event "message". Then, when the script reaches the dashes (or some other delimiter I can set), start over and create another event "message" and repeat for the entirety of failed cluster members.

In my mind it would be a for or while loop, but unsure how that should be structured. The end result would look something like this:

`var1=host1.domain.com
 var2=10.10.10.1
 var3=DISK_ERROR`

```
message -remote_host -port -msg "The host $var1 at IP $var2 is experiencing an issue of a $var3"
```

I have done a lot of searching over the past week and have not seen an example of this. It seems looping through a list is one thing and ending the list based on a delimiter is similar, but I haven't seen a usable example where you create multiple variables from an output, add them to an echo or some type of external action and then start over to create the same scenario again with another set of data from the same output. I could see writing to a file for each and then processing each if that would make sense, but at this point I am unsure how to accomplish, effectively, what I am asking. It may not be possible, but any advice on the best method to manipulate the data is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the rationale for assigning the field values to shell variables, if all you do is expand them again in the message string? why not create the message string directly from the record (in awk or perl for example)?

Answer (score 1):

Quick implementation in Awk:

```
awk -F ' *: *' '$1 ~ /Name/ { n = $2 } $1 ~ /Address/ { a = $2 } $1 ~ /Overall Health/ { m = $2 } /^--$/ {printf "The host %s at IP %s is experiencing an issue of a %s\n", n, a, m}'
```

Either pipe a command to this, or if you want to read from a file, put the name of the file at the end of the command.  (As written, it will wait for input from stdin.)